# Import node_modules to local files instead of importing from node_modules after build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundler, rollup, esbuild

I am currently using `tsup` and/or `unbuild` to bundle my own small library. I want to be able to import a third-party library, say `change-case`, and use the code. Whenever I build the project, is it possible for the bundler to add the code directly to my output file instead of it importing it from node_modules, which should make my bundle-size smaller, not being dependent on third party code? Is that possible?

This is what I mean:

**input file**

```js
import {camelCase} from "change-case"

const someFunction = (value: string) => camelCase(value)
```

### How output currently looks after build

```js
import {camelCase} from "change-case"

const someFunction = (value: string) => camelCase(value)
```

### How I want it to look after build

```js
const camelCase = (value: string) => {
    // whatever logic resides within the module
}

const someFunction = (value: string) => camelCase(value)
```

Meaning the end-user does not have to install `change-case` to their node_modules, they will only get the necessary parts from that library?

Answer (score 1):

You can set how imports are resolved in your builder config. The tag says you use rollup, where it is set by the [`inlineDynamicImports`](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-inlinedynamicimports) property:

```js
// in rollup.config.mjs
const config = defineConfig({
  plugins: [...],
  input: {...},
  output: {
    ...
    inlineDynamicImports: true,
    format: 'iife',
  },
});
```

Note that `inlineDynamicImports` does not work with all `format` types.